# Put decimal places on parse json data and display inside modal input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I display the product of subtotal and sum of amount due with two decimal places? When I add `toFixed(2)` at the end it gives me error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: modal.find(...).val(...).toFixed is not a function.

```
function view_sales(sales_id) {
    var modal = $('#sales-modal');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: url + 'GetSalesById', 
        data: { sales_id : sales_id }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            modal.modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
            modal.find($('#sales_id')).val(sales_id);
            modal.find($('#sales_po')).val(data.sales_po);
            modal.find($('#sales_so')).val(data.sales_so);
            modal.find($('#sales_dr')).val(data.sales_dr);
            modal.find($('#sales_si')).val(data.sales_si);
            modal.find($('#sales_particulars')).val(data.sales_particular);
            modal.find($('#sales_media')).val(data.sales_media);
            modal.find($('#sales_width')).val(data.sales_width);
            modal.find($('#sales_height')).val(data.sales_height);
            modal.find($('#sales_unit')).val(data.sales_unit);
            modal.find($('#sales_total_area')).val(data.sales_total_area);
            modal.find($('#sales_price_unit')).val(data.sales_price_unit);
            modal.find($('#sales_sub_total')).val(parseFloat(data.sales_total_area) * parseFloat(data.sales_price_unit)).toFixed(2);
            modal.find($('#sales_qty')).val(data.sales_qty);
            modal.find($('#sales_total')).val(data.sales_total);
            modal.find($('#sales_vat')).val(data.sales_vat);
            modal.find($('#sales_amount_due')).val(parseFloat(data.sales_total) + parseFloat(data.sales_vat)).toFixed(2);
            modal.find($('#sales_discount')).val(data.sales_discount);
            modal.find($('#sales_net_amount')).val(data.sales_net_amount);
            $('#modal-title').html('<i class="icon-add-to-list mr-2"></i>&nbsp; UPDATE SALES DETAILS');
            $('#btn-sales').html('Save Changes <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `toFixed` on string, because `val` method returns string.

You have to call `toFixed` on Number values like that:

```
modal.find($('#sales_sub_total')).val((parseFloat(data.sales_total_area) * parseFloat(data.sales_price_unit)).toFixed(2));
modal.find($('#sales_amount_due')).val((parseFloat(data.sales_total) + parseFloat(data.sales_vat)).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that you should provide a string selector to `find()`, not a jQuery object. The latter makes the `find()` operation redundant:

```
modal.find('#sales_id').val(sales_id);
modal.find('#sales_po').val(data.sales_po);
// and so on...
```

With regard to your actual issue, `val()` returns a string. You cannot call `toFixed()` on a string. Even if you could you'd need to call `toFixed()` on the argument you provide to the method, not the *result* of the function call.

Therefore to fix your issue wrap the calculation in parentheses to group it, then put `toFixed()` on that:

```js
modal.find('#sales_sub_total').val((parseFloat(data.sales_total_area) * parseFloat(data.sales_price_unit).toFixed(2));

modal.find('#sales_amount_due').val((parseFloat(data.sales_total) + parseFloat(data.sales_vat).toFixed(2));
```